# looping through an open layer feature object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, openlayers

I have an array of open layer feature object as:

```
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
const Data = [ 
    new Feature({ "ID": 101, "NAME": "ABC" }), 
    new Feature({ "ID": 102, "NAME": "XYZ" })
    ];
//looping through
                  <ListGroup>
                  {Data.map(function(name, id){
                      return (<ListGroup.Item action href="" key={id}>{name.NAME}</ListGroup.Item>)
                  })}
                  </ListGroup>
```

I get empty list elements and can not fetch NAME property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a feature is created with the `new Feature({})` constructor, it does not look quite like the property-object put into the constructor. The properties you passed into the new feature will be stored under `values` of that feature.

The full properties of an ol-feature can be accessed via `feature.getProperties()` single values can be accessed via `feature.get(key)`

In your example, in `Data.map` you named the first parameter `name` , which actually is the feature. This is a little bit confusing, i think `feature` or something similar would be a clearer variable name.

To get that features value, call `name.get('NAME')` (or `feature.get('NAME')`if you decide to rename the parameter)

Also, the second argument of `Array.map` is the index in the array, so in your case this will give you `0` and `1`, which is fine if these are the values you want. If you want to get the ID you can access these values by calling `name.get('ID')` or `feature.get('ID')` (see above). I guess i should mention the OpenLayers-Functions `feature.setId()` and `feature.getId()`, just for completions sake.

TL;Dr

Try `name.get('NAME')`instead of `name.NAME` and check the results

Comment: Thank you for saving me and providing clear explaination!! Was almost stucked with that.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead (remove double-quotations):

```
 new Feature({ ID: 101, NAME: "ABC" }), 
 new Feature({ ID: 102, NAME: "XYZ" })
```